# I want to add an imageButton to the scrollview and then manipulate it

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, android-button

Hi guys I have one button, if I click on this button I will see five buttons in the scrollview. My question is how I can manipulate the given buttons, for example if I click on button 2, I want the index of the button to be displayed in the textview.

Here is my code: MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var array_buttons = ArrayList<ImageButton>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        addButton()
        textView.setText("BUTTON")
    }

    //this dont working
    if ( array_buttons.size > 0 )
    {
        array_buttons[0].setOnClickListener()
        {
            textView.setText("0")
        }
    }
}

//fun for additive imageButtons on the scrollView
private fun addButton()
{
    var gallery = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.gallery)

    var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)

    for ( i in 0 until 5 )
    {
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, gallery, false)

        var image_button = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        image_button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

        gallery.addView(view)

        array_buttons.add(image_button)
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is always empty empty when you call it because your function add button is called only when the user click on the first button.
You must set your listener inside the addButton function as soon as you inflate your view.